# Update user profile property [PreferredName] throws PropertyNotEditableException in sharepoint 2013

Tags: 2013, development, sharepoint-server

I'm trying to update the PreferredName property in the User Profile. When trying to do so I get a PropertyNotEditableException.

```
                   using (SPSite elevatedSite = new SPSite(site.ID))
                   {
                       SPServiceContext serviceContext = SPServiceContext.GetContext(elevatedSite);
                       UserProfileManager profileManager = new UserProfileManager(serviceContext);
                       UserProfile userProfile = profileManager.GetUserProfile(true);

                       elevatedSite.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
                       userProfile["PreferredName"].Value = userData.PreferredName;

                       userProfile.Commit();

                   }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OOB properties are updated in a different way. The way you're trying is for updating custom properties. Use `userProfile[PropertyConstants.PreferredName]` and then try updating. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/microsoft.office.server.userprofiles.propertyconstants_fields.aspx

Update: Checking "allow user to edit property" for the user property solved issue for the OP.

Comment: It still did not work. I'm still getting error - Error updating user profile:  Property Not Editable: This property can only be modified by an administrator.

Comment: @KyleJohnson go to user profile properties and check if user can override setting and allow users to edit this property setting is checked. If unchecked, check both and try again.

Comment: The override setting - unchecked and it won't allow me to update it. The allow users to edit it - checked

Comment: @KyleJohnson Is it working with this?

Comment: :) updated answer